# Updating a table variable with joined table function output vs variable values?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Given the following table variable, which contains let's say some 10K records:

```
DECLARE @SomeTable TABLE
(
    ID int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(100),
    CustomerMailingAddress1 varchar(100),
    CustomerMailingAddress2 varchar(100),
    CustomerMailingAddress3 varchar(100),
    CustomerMailingAddress4 varchar(100),
    ContactInfo1 nvarchar(256),
    ContactInfo2 nvarchar(256)
)
```

Currently the table variable gets updated within a sproc as follows:

```
UPDATE st
SET
    ContactInfo1 = ci.ContactInfo1,
    ContactInfo2 = ci.ContactInfo2
FROM @SomeTable st, dbo.ContactInfoFunc() AS ci
```

The table function `dbo.ContactInfoFunc()` simply retrieves the `MAX` record according to primary key of a table with a single record (it's company contact info which will seldom if ever change).

Performance-wise is the above update more expensive? In other words, would there be any advantage to rewriting the update to eliminate the join to the table function output as follows:

```
DECLARE @ContactInfo1 nvarchar(256), @ContactInfo2 nvarchar(256)

SELECT @ContactInfo1 = ContactInfo1, @ContactInfo2 = ContactInfo2
FROM dbo.ContactInfoFunc()

UPDATE st
SET
    ContactInfo1 = @ContactInfo1,
    ContactInfo2 = @ContactInfo2
FROM @SomeTable st
```

Or is it a toss-up? Would the query optimizer be smart enough to cache the output of the table function or would it spin its wheels executing the function for each row being updated?

Comment: What is the point of storing the same output of the function in *every row* of the table? Why not just pull those as constants in the eventual query?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: That's what I was wondering, it seems like it would be better to just stick them in variables and assign them once in the update, especially since the function will only ever return a single pair of values.

Comment: Still don't understand why you need the *UPDATE* at all? If every row gets assigned the same value, what purpose does that column serve in the table?

Comment: I think the original intent was that the table in the db would be updated more frequently, but as it turns out it's only been updated once, with the initial values inserted, and subsequent changes have been datafixes to just update the columns of that sole record. It was planned for change that never ended up changing. The update to the table variable is one of several that update the subset grabbed by a query in sequence, and once done the table variable's records are inserted into a db table.

Comment: So you can still perform an insert into the final table by selecting the data in the table variable combined with constants as shown in my answer. Just prepend the `SELECT` with an appropriate `INSERT` command...

Comment: In terms of performance can you see any advantage to joining the table function as in the original UPDATE statement (putting aside that doing an update period is weird)?

Comment: If you insist on updating the table variable (which again, I have absolutely no bloody idea why you need to do that), then yes, it will be more expensive than if you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what else you're doing with the table variable, but why do you need to update it at all? Let's assume you just end up doing a `SELECT` from it at the end. So your code could easily be:

```
DECLARE @ContactInfo1 nvarchar(256), @ContactInfo2 nvarchar(256)

SELECT @ContactInfo1 = ContactInfo1, @ContactInfo2 = ContactInfo2
FROM dbo.ContactInfoFunc();

...

SELECT 
    ID,
    Name,
    CustomerMailingAddress1,
    CustomerMailingAddress2,
    CustomerMailingAddress3,
    CustomerMailingAddress4,
    ContactInfo1 = @ContactInfo1, -- these don't need to be a fixture in the table to
    ContactInfo2 = @ContactInfo2  -- be involved in the resultset or other activity...
FROM @SomeTable;
```

Now, my answer would be different if the function actually took parameters, and the output depended on those parameters. Then it might make sense to perform a `CROSS APPLY` perhaps... but again not to perform an `UPDATE`, just as a function of the final `SELECT`...